# Fixing Bosch SHE series insufficient fill issue? (SHE43R Series 300)

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Bosch SH43R dishwasher.  It has started not always filling enough on a cycle, leading to poor wash performance (often it can't even get the soap out of the dispenser).

Frustratingly, it's not every cycle.
Awkwardly, adding 2-3 cups of water sets things right (the water level then comes up a few cm above the drain mesh).  So I've been running it each night by listening for a lack of enough sloshing, then adding water by hand.  Ugh.

I've removed the integral filter and fill solenoid (Bosch part #00622058).  The filter was a little dirty, but not bad. I measured 4.1 gallons per minute out of the inlet hose: seems like plenty.  But the problem persists.

I know this model is a "timed fill" meaning the dishwasher computer has no idea how full the tub is.

[image: Bosh 00622058]

How can I run a diagnostic cycle, as this particular model has no display (other than a useless red LED that shines on the floor)?

What could be the low fill cause?  Can a weak solenoid do this?

Comment: Can you track down a service manual?  That might identify a way to change the timing.  At the same time, you don't know what the flow rate used to be, so try checking the inlet hose out.  Have you noticed any significant difference in the peak flow from some other line in your  house (preferably not one for a sink, as the faucet may restrict flow).

Comment: This washer has a flow regulator, and is supposed to work regardless of house water pressure.  If anything, this house has too high pressure.  It does not vary.

Comment: If the filter is plugged or the pressure is two low with a timed fill it will not be enough water water.

Comment: @EdBeal the question specifies the filter is removed and the pressure is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the fill solenoid, Bosch part #00622058.  My kids and I ran a bucket test, operating the valve into a bucket and timing flow over one minute:

[image: Bosch fill solenoid testing]

Don't do this at home (ahem), note the bare wires from the scavenged extension cord: it's a 120V solenoid.

Test runs produced 5,8 and then 6 cups of water in one minute *with the filter completely removed*.  This explains the inconsistent behavior.  The new solenoid from the local parts store produced 12 cups in the same condition.

The hose was grotty also, and is going back to FluidMaster under Warranty:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just got a brand new Bosch today and had problem.. Do NOT take out the filter that is in the water supply input, it is compresses the valve to let water in. I found mine in the trash, but it back in and all is fine.